# Test reports always consist of same linear graph

Tags: report, record, analyzer, grinder

I use Grinder 3.11. I installed the Grinder Alnalyser "GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19" to view the final report of the test run. I ran the following test for 20 iterations:

```
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder 
from net.grinder.script import Test 
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPRequest 
from java.lang import System 

class TestRunner: 
        def __init__(self): 
                grinder.statistics.delayReports=True 
        def __call__(self): 
                Google() 

request = HTTPRequest()
Test(1, "Google").record(request) 

def Google(): 
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() 
        result = request.GET("http://www.google.com") 
        timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() 
        googlet = timeTaken - currentTime 
        grinder.logger.info(" vij google time " + str(googlet)) 
        grinder.statistics.forLastTest.success = True
```

After running the test, Transaction per second graph was a linear graph (improper graph with just one value recorded).

The TPS graph is the same for any test I run. What could be the cause of this? Why are the response times not recorded for all the iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Grinder Analyzer expects a larger data set than you are providing it.  Try running with 2000 iterations, or 20,000.  Otherwise, as you can see, the graphs generated are not very useful.